# How to pass the value for Djava.security.policy

Tags: shell

I am editing one xml file with the value 
-`Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/oacore/config/java2.policy`

I am keeping this value in a file and passing this to the xml

and result coming as below :

`Djava.security.policy=/j2ee/oacore/config/java2.policy`  >>> why $ORACLE_HOME excluding not sure

but I want the value like 
-`Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/oacore/config/java2.policy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property expansion is similar to expanding variables in a shell. That is, when a string like

```
${some.property}
```

---

Try this

```
Djava.security.policy=${ORACLE_HOME}/j2ee/oacore/config/java2.policy
```

[Refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

Comment: I have tried above one but still it is not passing $ORACLE_HOME

Comment: The "-Djava.security.policy" policy file value will be ignored (for both java and appletviewer commands) if the "policy.allowSystemProperty" property in the security properties file is set to false. The default is true.
Changing the Policy Implementation

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, I am able to write the code using Djava.security.policy=\$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/oacore/config/java2.policy  Thanks for cooperation , Thanks SM

Comment: I have provided link..you can see like your code \$ORACLE_HOME/ @user2500742